# What are the mandatory fields of FeedItem Object?

Tags: feeditem

I was wandering what are the mandatory fields of FeedItem Object ?

Comment: Just FYI, I suspect you got downvoted because the question illustrates that ou put very little effort into trying to answer the question yourself before asking the question. The documentation is easily available and even if if wasn't you could have tried inserting a record and looking at the errors that cam back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Body** - The content of the FeedItem. Required when Type is TextPost. Optional when Type is ContentPost or LinkPost.

**ContentData** - This field is required if Type is ContentPost.

**ContentFileName** - This field is required if Type is ContentPost

Go through the below doc for detailed info -

You can check for other details about the fields mentioned above and all the remaining fields of FeedItem object in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm).

**EDIT**

As Rohit pointed out, ParentId is also a mandatory field

**ParentId** - ID of the object type to which the FeedItem object is related

Comment: `ParentId` is also an required field.

Comment: Yes.My Bad.Forgot that. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @GAURAV - Please mark it as the answer if this answers your question